# How many strings with seven or more characters can be formed from the letters of EVERGREEN.

Tags: probability-theory

**Question:**
How many strings with seven  or more characters can be formed from the letters of EVERGREEN.

> I'm lost on this one, the answer is supposed to be 19, 635.

**My Attempt:**
I've tried using the permutations with indistinguishable objects formula (some letters repeat),

$$P([n_1,n_2,\dots,n_k], n) = \dfrac{n!}{n_1!n_2!\dots n_k!}$$

Where $n$ is the number of objects overall (including repetitions). And the $n1,n2,…,nk$ are the repetition count. 
Added the results for $n = 7, 8, 9$ but only got $8505$.

Comment: @ozo: Why not? ${}{}$

Comment: "...can be formed from the letters of EVERGREEN". There are only 9 of them.

Comment: The cases for 7,8 letters need a little care. When you select 8 letters, for example, you may not select all of the Es.

Comment: @copper.hat I'm still confused, I use ${9+7-1}\choose{7}$ to determine how many different words when $n$ = 7, but I reckon its counting duplicate.

Comment: It is not that straightforward. For 7 letters, you need to count 6 different situations: (1) 2E, (2) 2R, (3) 1E 1R, (4) 1 E 0 R, (5) 0 E 1 R, (6) 0E 0R, if you see what I mean.

Comment: @copper.hat Thanks, that clears it all up.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\binom nk$ tells you the number of subsets of $k$ letters you can choose from $n$ letters.  How many different ways can I arrange $k$ letters?

Comment: Upon further review, this answer is essentially useless.  See copper.hat's comment.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote down, what I have calculated. The letters in the brackets represent the letters, which are not regarded any more.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check out the explanation of correct answer i.e. 19635 here: http://www.techtud.com/doubt/combinatorics-how-many-strings-seven-or-more-chara

Comment: Even if this link is interesting, it could be much better you explain in your answer.